# What material can I use for the front service panel of this tub?

Tags: bathtub

I recently replaced a 23 year-old tub, in a bathroom that was perfectly sized for the original tub; I had no spare inches to work with, along either horizontal dimension.  This meant that I had to find a tub with the exact same footprint dimensions.

I did find one, and the spouse is happy with it functionally.  But now begins the problem of making it *actually look good*.  The problem I have is that tub manufacturing has changed somewhat in the near quarter-century that has transpired.

The old tub was made entirely of cultured marble, and had its own integrated 60x42 top deck with helpful straight edges and right-angle corners.  It was a "drop in" tub, in the sense that the home-builder built up a stud frame to support it from underneath.  But it didn't actually drop in to a finished, pretty deck that was longer or wider than itself, because *it was its own deck*.  So the way the home-builder finished the install was to caulk-in a rectangular sheet of quarter-inch cultured marble to hide the supporting studs.  This single large sheet was considered the service panel.  So if you ever needed to access the plumbing (upgrade fixture, etc.) you'd just cut the caulk, and wiggle the sheet of cultured marble out of the way.

The new tub (shown below) is also 60x42, but is constructed very differently.  It is acrylic, which I gather was molded in some giant vacuum form/press.   Instead of having a solid & uniform 3/4 inch deck that terminates at square & straight edges, it has "flanged" edges that bend down at an angle that is only *mostly* vertical, and only *approximates* "straight".  Also the corners eventually turn a full 90 degrees, but they take their sweet time getting there.  And the flanged edge tends to hang a little lower at those corners than it does during the approximately-straight runs (60 inches, and 42 inches).

This is all because the manufactures of these acrylic drop-in tubs seem to all assume that someone will buy their drop-in tub and drop it in to some finished deck that is at least a few inches wider & longer than the tub itself.  But as I noted at the start of this DIY question, I don't have that luxury.  I had no spare inches in which to build out a deck surface, and need to rely on the tub's own deck as being the totality of all deckage... just like the OG tub.

So with all of that explained, here is the question itself:  I need to come up with a front service panel for this new tub, very much like what the old tub had.  It would ideally be:

- one piece
- not super heavy
- about a quarter-inch thick
- needs to take paint well (ideally with little to no texture)

... and it will need to be a material than I can work the top edge of (filing, sanding, etc.), so that I can contour it to mate well with the *approximately* straight edges and radius'd square corners.

***What modern material would be good for this application, in a necessarily wet environment?***

My plan is to rely on both rare-earth magnets and caulk to hold it in place.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ignoring the paint aspect, and possibly the one-piece aspect, I'd consider large-format tiles, or any-format tiles on a backerboard as the "panel" (in fact, I am considering just that, as I have a somewhat similar tub in very similar present condition.) Shaping is a simple matter of diamond tooling and dust-masks.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that would be one heavy access panel—sounds like the OP wants access to the entire front of the tub (and maybe the side too, although that *could* be a separate panel).

Comment: Why does the top edge need to mate so perfectly with the countours of the tub?  Why can't it be dead straight, with the tub sitting on top of it, the way it was designed?  IE, to drop in.    Why do you need access panels on this side of the tub?  None of the machinery or supply/drainage connection is on this side.  Do a google image search for "drop in tub" and you'll see a hundred ways to do it, but none of them conforming to the constraints you have set yourself.

Comment: Alternative to "conforming" to your tub rim, would you consider an acrylic front that sits *beneath* your tub rim?  IE it would slide up between the top framing and the lip of the tub?  It would not have to be any particular thickness, or conform perfectly to anything and would not need to be painted.  You just buy a white acrylic sheet.  It would be very light weight and could be held to the frame with invisible clips or magnets or screws with white plastic caps.

Comment: @jay613 :  (1 of 2) Actually, the pump reset (left), drain & overflow gaskets (center) and air intake check-valve (center) are all on this side.  After posting this question and going to bed, it did occur to me that I could have the tub rest on the top edge of a thicker sheet of material, and that may look good.  I agree with you that none of my google searches conformed to my question.

Comment: @jay613 : (2 of 2) I can't bring myself to think that having the lip/flange of the tub hang over a skirt panel would look good.  I'm not sure it would pass the spousal test.
(Also on this side, requiring access for servicing:  pneumatic switches for pump and air mixture))

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/bjR0ALJ) for comparison is a free standing tub built as with (2of2).  The tub, top rim, and all the machinery are one piece and the outside walls are a thin acrylic shell tucked under the lip of the tub.  This is obviously different from your tub but just to show you this approach can look good.    I'm pretty sure I've seen standard tubs built this way too, with a manufactured plastic side tucked under the rim.

Comment: @Huesmann I did say "Ignoring...and possibly the one-piece aspect" in mentioning my tile approach.

Comment: @GogTheGuilder have you considered a top edge similar to a Z flashing for siding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try an acrylic product like [StarBoard](https://www.boatoutfitters.com/cut-to-size-arctic-white-king-starboard?gclid=Cj0KCQiA0oagBhDHARIsAI-Bbgc6nd6-v7b5Gq1n5kq1iV5rq1Jb-ge-hLYCc1FBZy3DgvA49TTe0GoaAqS4EALw_wcB#215=228&211=1111)

It is expensive but has all the qualities that you need.
Our local big box home store here has it in stock, but others may not.  You may have to search online or order it.

Comment: Starboard is a good plain choice, but you'll find all kind of textures/patterns if you google "shower acrylic panels". Kohler Choreograph is but one of a zillion examples.  You can cut it relatively easily, though it would require an edging strip (generally available) for a finished looking edge.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I'll look into it.  I'm adjusting my thinking to also consider having this tub appear to rest on the service panel (which could then extend slightly proud of the tub's lip/flange), rather than appear flush.  This would require a thicker panel, and so then I'd have to accept more weight.

Comment: Look up "tub aprons", these are panels for exactly this situation.  You may get a perfect fit or maybe need to do a little artistry at the corners but better than building from scratch with flat panels.